# How to animate 2D characters using swift for a fighting game?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

Hello I have a basic knowledge of programming in swift and also one simple app on the store already.
I have an idea of a new app which would include some animations. It would be very simple "fighting game". I want to animate a 2D characters which would be drawn frame by frame. Something similar to old 2D fighting games "street fighter etc."
I don't know where to start. What tools do I need to use? Do I have to learn SpriteKit? Or is there some better simpler way? Can you guide me where to start and how to achieve by goal? All I need is for the character to do a few simple moves. It doesn't have to be smooth as an animated movie but it has to look like the character is hitting the other one. I will hire someone to draw the pictures for me I just want to do the coding  Thank you for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a correct answer to this question without providing additional details. It all kind of depends on what your app is supposed to do exactly. If it's a game, then it would be reasonable to learn SpriteKit since that gives you a head start and a lot of things that help in game-related mechanics out of the box, like hitboxes, movement, characters, score etc.

It also depends on what kind of animation you would want to achieve. If it's for example, just a static character on screen, that moves one arm, maybe you could achieve the animation effect with UIKit, by just rotating/moving a view, that represents the arm. I'm just giving you an example.

If you just want to create some kind of repeatable animation, like a .gif image, then you can just loop an array of images/sprites/frames and create an illusion of animation.

```
var imageView = UIImageView()
let arrayOfImageNames = ["frame1.png", "frame2.png", "frame3.png"] //etc
let imageFrames = arrayOfImageNames.compactMap{ UIImage(named: $0) } //get all the image frames as [UIImage]
imageView.animationImages = imageFrames
imageView.animationDuration = 2 //duration of animation in seconds
imageView.startAnimating()
```

Like I said, it all kind of depends on what you want to create, and how complicated you want your app to be and how the animated character interacts with its environment.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I will specify what I mean. I want to hire an illustrator to make similar sheet for me with less moves https://www.spriters-resource.com/fullview/60224/ But I don't need the character to move around the screen. The fight will happen only as reaction to certain actions. For example the fight will happen as a result of an answer in a text game. So the player will choose to attack and then the attack will happen. So there is no need of moving the characters around the screen also no need  for AI etc. I just wont to make a few prepared moves and reactions.

Comment: In that case, I believe that the image looping code above (gif basically) would be enough. Anything else would be overkill.